# Translates by infinite subset of finite index subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinite-groups

Given a countable group $\Gamma$ and a finite index subgroup $\Gamma_0$ and an infinite subset $S \subset \Gamma$ such that $S \cap \Gamma_0 = \emptyset$ can one conclude that $\Gamma_0 \cup S \Gamma_0 = \Gamma$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}$, $\Gamma_0 = 3\mathbb{Z}$, and $S = 3\mathbb{Z} + 1$.